# Prediction with lme4 on new levels

Tags: r, prediction, lme4, mixed-models, random-effects

I'm trying to fit a mixed effects model and then use that model to generate estimates on a new dataset that may have different levels.  I expected that the estimates on a new dataset would use the mean value of the estimated parameters, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Here's a minimum working example:

```
library(lme4)
d = data.frame(x = rep(1:10, times = 3),
               y = NA,
               grp = rep(1:3, each = 10))
d$y[d$grp == 1] = 1:10 + rnorm(10)
d$y[d$grp == 2] = 1:10 * 1.5 + rnorm(10)
d$y[d$grp == 3] = 1:10 * 0.5 + rnorm(10)
fit = lmer(y ~ (1+x)|grp, data = d)
newdata = data.frame(x = 1:10, grp = 4)
predict(fit, newdata = newdata, allow.new.levels = TRUE)
```

In this example, I'm essentially defining three groups with different regression equations (slopes of 1, 1.5 and 0.5).  However, when I try to predict on a new dataset with an unseen level, I get a constant estimate.  I would have expected the expected value of the slope and intercept to be used to generate predictions for this new data.  Am I expecting the wrong thing?  Or, what am I doing wrong with my code?

Comment: I believe `predict.merMod` just uses the coefficients from the fixed effects parts of the model for new levels. `y ~ x + (x|grp)` is a more sensible model specification.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!  If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I generally wouldn't include a random slope without including a fixed slope. It seems like `predict.merMod` agrees with me, because it seems to simply use only the fixed effects to predict for new levels. The documentation says "the prediction will use the unconditional (population-level) values for data with previously unobserved levels", but these values don't seem to be estimated with your model specification.

Thus, I suggest this model:

```
fit = lmer(y ~ x + (x|grp), data = d)
newdata = data.frame(x = 1:10, grp = 4)
predict(fit, newdata = newdata, allow.new.levels = TRUE)
#       1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10 
#1.210219  2.200685  3.191150  4.181616  5.172082  6.162547  7.153013  8.143479  9.133945 10.124410
```

This is the same as only using the fixed effects part of the model:

```
t(cbind(1, newdata$x) %*% fixef(fit))
#         [,1]     [,2]    [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
#[1,] 1.210219 2.200685 3.19115 4.181616 5.172082 6.162547 7.153013 8.143479 9.133945 10.12441
```

Comment: I understand that this will still use the fixed effects only in the new prediction. But, how do you add the random effects?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: As you said before: 'predict.merMod just uses the coefficients from the fixed effects parts of the model for new levels'. Is there a way to also include the random effects (x|grp)?

Comment: Sure, that's the default. You just need to use the default `allow.new.levels = FALSE`. Of course, you can't predict random effects for new levels (which have not been part of the training data). That's conceptually not possible.

Comment: I see. I am interested in finding an estimation of the random effects for a completely new subject, I guess I am using the wrong approach. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it's not clear enough, but I think the documentation for `?predict.merMod` states (reasonably) clearly what happens when `allow.new.levels=TRUE`.  I guess the ambiguity might be in what
"unconditional (population-level) values" means ...

> `allow.new.levels`: logical if new levels (or NA values) in ‘newdata’ are
> allowed. If FALSE (default), such new values in ‘newdata’
> will trigger an error; if TRUE, then the prediction will use
> the unconditional (population-level) values for data with
> previously unobserved levels (or NAs).

"Unconditional (population-level)" means that the corresponding random effect components are set to zero  — which is what we do if we cannot *condition* on the observed data for a particular group, since we don't want to specify that the prediction is for a particular group

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar confusion as the original poster.  Can you please elaborate on how 'allow.new.levels' works?  What is an unconditional (population-level) value?

Comment: unconditional/population-level means that the corresponding random effects are set to zero (which is what we would do if we cannot **condition on** the fact that an observation comes from a particular group)

Comment: Appreciate the answer.  Is `predict.merMod` robust for complex cases, where for example, a hierarchical term `individual\family` is being predicted for a new `individual` but a known `family`?  I assume what makes sense here is to set the coefficient for the new `individual` to zero but use the fit coefficient for the appropriate `family`.

Comment: Yes. You can either use `re.form` to include/exclude relevant terms, or make the specified family a new (previously unobserved) level and use `allow.new.levels = TRUE`